# How to calculate the overall entropy when continuous 2D positions are known?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, solid-state-physics, entropy

If I have the positions of particles in continuous 2D space, how do I calculate the entropy of the system? The particles are invariant, I just need some measure of how organised they are, but I'm not sure how to calculate that. I think I need to integrate the population density over both dimensions?

Comment: I think any system in which you know the exact positions of any given particle has $0$ position related entropy, am I wrong? There has to be some uncertainty

Comment: I was thinking if all the particles are clustered together, it would have a low entropy value, and for less organised systems with the particles spread evenly, it would be high - or do I need some other name?

Comment: This will be somewhat weird suggestion but you could fit the data to a multivariate Gaussian and investigate the covariance matrix :D Basically if there is no inherent statistics, fit a distribution to it and investigate that

Comment: Thanks @acarturk, I see what you mean. Once I have the distribution, how will I know the entropy? I have only calculated it for things on lattices before with very finite combinations

Comment: Well that still isn't a valid way to obtain entropy though: It's just a measure of how clustered the particles are, which isn't entropy (it might be somewhat related though so... I'll wait for a better answer). $S=0$ if you know the exact positions of particles either way though

Comment: Oh but you can say, a more clustered system has less entropy than a less clustered one, given we only know the macroscopic picture of the system

Comment: Yes, I think ```S=0``` only when all the particles are at the same point? I'm not sure we need uncertainty. If we just had a few snapshots in time of the particles, we'd say they had low entropy before spreading out to the high entropy, like perfume dispersing in a room?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118907/discussion-between-acarturk-and-lizardinablizzard).